# Exorbitant overhead of openMP parallel region

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, profiling, openmp, trace

I have following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < BIG_INT ~O(1e5); ++i)
{
    intialize()
    TIMER_START("T1")
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        TIMER_START("T2")

        // Some big chunk of work 

        TIMER_START("T2")
    }
    TIMER_STOP("T1")
}
```

Timer T1 and T2 measure time spend inside and outside pragmas. For each thread, there is its own copy of timer T2. T1 and T2 are cumulative timer.

Here is the part that stumps me most. The total time reported by timer T1 is ~19 seconds, While T2 timer reports time varying from 11-14 seconds.

So seemingly 5 seconds is spent in parallel overhead which seems exorbitant. Any clue what might be causing it ?

My guess is that, there might be some load imbalance? How do I verify this hypothesis?

Comment: So you figured out that creating an OMP thread team and starting its threads and, above all, waiting for all of them to complete costs about 50 microseconds.  That's pretty good.

Comment: You should post your real code, or at least a more representative extract from it.  What you have posted doesn't do any work sharing, the `parallel` directive on its own simply requires all threads to execute whatever is inside the directive's scope.  If all the threads are executing the same code are there races for the timer `T2` ?  Load imbalance would show in the variance of measurements of `T2` across threads.

Comment: You might also want to look into the EPCC OpenMP benchmarks.  It's a suite of microbenchmarks that focus on different aspects of OpenMP and measure their runtime overhead.

Comment: Based on the execution trace, it seems that load balancing among the the thread is issue. Recall that program runs for many iterations and time gather is only cumulative.

Comment: You also need to tell us how your timer is programmed.  Are you using calls to a system clock function which reports CPU time ?  Or something like `omp_get_wtime` which reports wallclock time ?

Comment: I use TAU for instrumentation and generating trace!